# json response with 2 table in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

why my code get error

```
  public function AuditorBagian_Edit($nopek)
  {

    $user = User::where('nopek', '=', $nopek)->get();
    $bagian_user = Bagian::all()->where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get();

    return response()->json($bagian_user);

  }
```

I want to show data from Bagian

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you don't need `all()->`

Comment: try `$user = User::where('nopek', '=', $nopek)->first();
$bagian_user = Bagian::where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Error result of code

`$bagian_user = Bagian::all()->where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get();`

`Bagian::all()` return instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and find all records in db, then you try to filter `->where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get()` specific records but this code wrong because method `where()` of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` class  return instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and this class does not have`get()` method.

`User::where('nopek', '=', $nopek)->get()` also return instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. To get single record use `first()` method instead of `get()`

The correct way get result is

```
$user = User::where('nopek', '=', $nopek)->first();

if(!empthy($user)) {
    $bagian_user = Bagian::where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get().
}
```

Edited, format php code

Answer (score 1):

You can pass collection or array into **response()->json()** function it will convert as **JSON** data

```
 public function AuditorBagian_Edit($nopek)
          {

            $user = User::where('nopek', '=', $nopek)->get();
            $bagian_user = Bagian::where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get();
    // or $bagian_user = Bagian::where('kode_bagian', '=', $user->bagian)->get()->toArray();

            return response()->json($bagian_user);

          }
```

Comment: This might return more than 1 user, so it might not work in certain situations, I would use first() instead like Davit suggested in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the ::all() will do, all() and get() is the same behaviour.

Take not that all(), get(), first() is the final step to get the model data, the condition and with() and ordering() and etc must happen before all the three above mentioned